# Jquery change text of an option in another selected option which is inside an .each() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I have a few rooms which each contain the same 2 select dropdowns. When I select the option with the value of 4 in the number of persons dropdown I want the text of the next option (the dinner select) to change, but ONLY the text of the option under the room I selected. Currently it changes the option values of both the dinner option dropdowns. I know it is because of the `.each()` function, and I also tried `.change` and `.on('change')`, but to no avail.

HTML:

```
<form class="booking-form needs-validation" name="book-room-form" action="" id="contactForm" method="post" novalidate>

    <h1>Star Wars Room</h1>

    <table class="table room-table" data-price-p-person="400" data-ss="200">
      <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">
                <label class="form-check-label selected-label" for="room-selected">Select</label>                                                   
            </th>
        </tr>

      </thead>
      <tbody>

     <tr>                                           
        <td class="persons"> 
            <select class="browser-default custom-select num-person select-update" name="number-persons-selection" required disabled>
              <option value="0" selected>Select Number of Persons</option>
              <option value="1">1 person R600</option>
              <option value="2">2 persons R800</option>
              <option value="3">3 persons R1200</option>
              <option value="4">2 adults and one child under 5 years</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="dinner">
            <select class="browser-default custom-select num-dinner select-update" name="dinner-selection" disabled>
              <option value="0" selected>Select Dinner Course</option>
              <option class="option-two-course-dinn" value="120">Two Course Dinner R120</option>
              <option class="option-three-course-dinn" value="200">Three Course Dinner R200</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="view-total">
        <td><label for="room-total" class="tot">Total: R <input type="text" name="room-total" class="total" size="6" value="0" readonly="readonly" /></label></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<h1>Game of Thrones Room</h1>

    <table class="table room-table" data-price-p-person="400" data-ss="200">
      <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">
                <label class="form-check-label selected-label" for="room-selected">Select</label>                                                   
            </th>
        </tr>

      </thead>
      <tbody>

     <tr>                                           
        <td class="persons"> 
            <select class="browser-default custom-select num-person select-update" name="number-persons-selection" required disabled>
              <option value="0" selected>Select Number of Persons</option>
              <option value="1">1 person R600</option>
              <option value="2">2 persons R800</option>
              <option value="3">3 persons R1200</option>
              <option value="4">2 adults and one child under 5 years R800</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="dinner">
            <select class="browser-default custom-select num-dinner select-update" name="dinner-selection" disabled>
              <option value="0" selected>Select Dinner Course</option>
              <option class="option-two-course-dinn" value="120">Two Course Dinner R120</option>
              <option class="option-three-course-dinn" value="200">Three Course Dinner R200</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="view-total">
        <td><label for="room-total" class="tot">Total: R <input type="text" name="room-total" class="total" size="6" value="0" readonly="readonly" /></label></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<div class="grand-total-cont"><label for="grand-total" class="tot">Grand Total (inclusive with number of days): R <input type="text" class="grandtotal" size="6" value="0" readonly="readonly" name="grand-total" /></label></div>


<button name="submit-request" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
      <input type="hidden" name="submitted" id="submitted" value="true" />

</form>
```

Jquery:

```
$('body').on('change', '.select-update', function(e){

        $('.room-table').each(function(){
            var persons_price = $(this).data('price-p-person');
            var ss = $(this).data('ss');

            var num_persons = Number($(this).find('.num-person').val());

            if(num_persons >= 1) {
                var dinner = Number($(this).find('.num-dinner').val());
                var room_cost = persons_price * num_persons;

                var dinner_costs = num_persons * dinner;


                if(num_persons == 1){
                    room_cost = room_cost + ss;
                }
                else if(num_persons == 4){
                    room_cost = persons_price * 2;

                    dinner_costs = dinner * 2;
//here is the issue
                    $('.num-person option:selected').each(function(){
                        $(".num-dinner").find(".option-two-course-dinn").text('Adult 2 course dinner ' + dinner + ' pp Child under 5 Free');
                        $(".num-dinner").find('.option-three-course-dinn').text('Adult 3 course dinner ' + dinner + ' pp Child under 5 Free');
                    });

                }

                var total = room_cost + dinner_costs;

            }
            else total = 0;
            $(this).find('.total').val(total);
            total = 0;
            $('.total').each(function(){
                val = $(this).val() | 0;
                total = val ? (parseFloat(total + val)) : total;
            });
            var num_days = $('.date-picks').find("#days").val();
            $('.grandtotal').val(total * num_days);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the code:

```
if(num_persons == 1){
    room_cost = room_cost + ss;
    $(this).find(".num-dinner .option-two-course-dinn").text('Two Course Dinner R120');
    $(this).find('.num-dinner .option-three-course-dinn').text('Three Course Dinner R200');
} else if(num_persons == 4){
    room_cost = persons_price * 2;

    dinner_costs = dinner * 2;

    $(this).find(".num-dinner .option-two-course-dinn").text('Adult 2 course dinner ' + dinner + ' pp Child under 5 Free');
    $(this).find('.num-dinner .option-three-course-dinn').text('Adult 3 course dinner ' + dinner + ' pp Child under 5 Free');

 }
```

this is a demo link https://jsfiddle.net/ryannghiem/vfjdu90c/3/

Comment: Thank you, that worked. But now if I decide to select e.g 1 Person again the original text does not change back, how would I approach this?

Comment: Pls edit your question. I edited my answer with that you want. And dont forget accept my answer, vote up it

Comment: thanks I will upvote, how do you want me to edit the question? Last question - is it possible to make the code look like DRY? I am going to have several more selects, and also a lot more options

Comment: @Horcrux I think you should show more code, example for this idea with new question. Its clear